# TextBox для ввода и стиль

Tags: avalonia

Делаю SelectAll() для ввода потому как при корректировке если это цифирь то вводят все заново , а если буки то нажмут стрелочку направо и встанут куда надо . А тут по умолчанию Foreground почему-то не меняется на белое при выделении,  а Background темно синий и текст виден плохо . Тогда делаю стиль TextBox:focus Background белам и все красиво но до тех пор пока не нажмешь стрелочку направо , тогда текст получается белым на белом фоне , то есть исчезает . Как решается эта проблема че-та я торможу .

Comment: Уточняю вопрос : какое событие происходит при потере выделения текста в TexBox ?